# Is there a way to check of .jar is in development mode still or in designer in IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Im using swing to build an interface but im wondering if is there a way to check if particular .jar is still in development or if its in swing designer.
i've figure out that i can check if it is in debugger mode, but dont know about others.

Comment: can you clarify what does .jar being "still in development" mean, technically?

Comment: i mean that when im using windowbuilder in eclipse it gets swing classes but im also using components created by 3rd company and is there a way to check if its "running" in designer?